Extremal of a functional with one variable endpoint
Consider the functional $$J[y] = \int \limits_{0}^{b} {\frac{\sqrt{y'^2 + 1}}{y} \text{d}x}$$ with $y(0) = 0$ and the other endpoint somewhere along the circle $(x-9)^2 + y^2 - 9 = 0$ (call this circle $\sigma(x, y)$). What is the value of $b$ for the extremal?

My work:
The Euler-Lagrange Equation for the functional will be $$\begin{align*} F_y - \frac{d}{dx} [F_{y'}] = 0 &\implies -\frac{\sqrt{y'^2 + 1}}{y^2} - \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \frac{y'}{y \sqrt{y'^2 + 1}} \right] = 0 \newline & \implies \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \frac{y'}{y \sqrt{y'^2 + 1}} \right] = -\frac{\sqrt{y'^2 + 1}}{y^2} \end{align*}$$
At the same time, since $F(y, y')$ does not depend on $x$ explicitly, we can use the Beltrami identity: $$\begin{align*} F - y' \cdot F_{y'} = K \implies \frac{\sqrt{y'^2 + 1}}{y} - y' \cdot \frac{y'^2}{y \sqrt{y'^2 + 1}} = K \implies \cdots \implies y \sqrt{y'^2 + 1} = C \end{align*}$$ where $C = \frac{1}{K}$ is an arbitrary constant.
This is a separable ODE that ends up solving to $y(x) = \sqrt{C^2 - (c_1 - x)^2}$, where $c_1$ is (yet) another constant of integration.
Plugging in the initial condition that $y(0) = 0$, the most I can say is that $|C| = |c_1|$, which doesn't simplify anything much.
Now, the transversality condition says that at $x = b$, $y'(b) = - \frac{1}{\sigma'(b)}$, where $\sigma$ is the circle given at the beginning.
Since we have the equation for the circle, I proceeded to differentiate $\sigma$ implicitly with respect to $x$: $$\begin{align*} \frac{d \sigma}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}[(x-9)^2 + y^2 - 9] = -\frac{x - 9}{y} & \implies \sigma'(b) = -\frac{b - 9}{y(b)} \newline & \implies -\frac{1}{\sigma'(b)} = \frac{y(b)}{b - 9} \end{align*} \tag{1}$$
Since at $x = b$, $y$ will be on the circle, $(b - 9)^2 + y(b)^2 - 9 = 0 \implies y(b) = \sqrt{9 - (b - 9)^2}$.
Lastly, since we have that $y'(x) = \frac{\sqrt{C^2 - y^2}}{y}$ from the Beltrami identity, we set this equal to the result from $(1)$ and get that
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\sqrt{C^2 - y(b)^2}}{y(b)} = \frac{y(b)}{b - 9} \implies b &= 9 + \frac{y(b)^2}{\sqrt{C^2 - y(b)^2}} = 9 + \frac{9 - (b - 9)^2}{\sqrt{C^2 - 9 + (b - 9)^2}} \newline &= 9 - \frac{(b - 12)(b - 6)}{\sqrt{C^2 + (b - 12)(b - 6)}}
\end{align*}$$
At this point, I plugged in the equation for $b$ into Mathematica and got the following results for $b$: $$b = \frac{1}{2} \left(18 \pm \sqrt{-C^2 \pm \sqrt{C^4-54 C^2+81}+27} \right)$$

My question: Is this correct? I started off feeling like I would get a concrete number for $b$, since we're given a concrete circle $\sigma(x, y)$. I got some answers, but I can't help feeling like there's something seriously wrong somewhere.

I suspect the problem is ill-defined: $J[y]$ diverges at $x=0$ if $y=\sqrt{C^2-(C-x)^2}.$

I hadn't thought about that.
I wonder if taking the limit of the integral as the lower bound approaches 0 does anything...

Hint.
The two circles
$$
\cases{
(x-c_1)^2 + y^2 = c_1^2\\
(x-9)^2 + y^2 = 3^2
}
$$
should intersect orthogonally so
$$
c_1^2+3^2 = (9-c_1)^2\Rightarrow c_1 = 4
$$

NOTE
Given
$$
\cases{
g_1(x,y) = (x-c_1)^2 + y^2 - c_1^2 = 0\\
g_2(x,y) = (x-9)^2 + y^2 - 3^2=0
}
$$
$b$ is determined by solving for $\{b, c_1\}$
$$
\cases{
\nabla g_1(b)\cdot\nabla g_2(b) = (b-c_1)(b-9)+\sqrt{c_1^2-(b-c_1)^2}\sqrt{9-(b-9)^2}=0\\
(b-c_1)^2 - c_1^2 = (b-9)^2 - 3^2
}
$$
thus obtaining $b =\frac{36}{5}, c_1 = 4$.

I see (the solution I got is indeed a circle).
How does your last line follow from the two equations above it? From those equations, I can only see that $c^2_1 + 3^2 = (x - c_1)^2 + (x - 9)^2 + 2y^2$.

Please. See figure attached.

Thank you for the figure. I guess it’s the algebra that is troubling me: the only way I can see to eliminate the $y^2$ term is to plug in $x=9$, which gives you $(9-c_1)^2+y^2=c^2$ for the first equation and $y^2=3^2$ for the second one. Adding the negative of the second one to the first one gives $(9-c_1)^2=c_1^2-9 \implies \cdots \implies c_1=5$. How did you get $c_1 = 4$?

A mere replacement does not solve the problem. It is necessary to observe the condition of transversality.

@JOlv Given two functions $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$, continuous and differentiable at $x=b$, what is the geometric meaning of $y_1'(b)=−\frac{1}{y_2'(b)}$?

I figured it out, I just had't gotten around to updating the post.
It looks like we did something similar: Basically, I took the radius vectors for the two circles and added the squares of their lengths. Since they are orthogonal, and we know the radii of the two circles (one of them is $9$ and the other one is $c^2$), we get from the Pythagorean Theorem that $$[(c - b)^2 + y_b^2] + [(9 - b)^2 + y_b^2] = (9 - c)^2 \implies [c^2] + [9] = (9 - c)^2$$ $$\implies c = 4 \implies 4^2 - (x - 4)^2 = 3^2 - (x - 9)^2 \implies x = b = 7.2$$
Many thanks once again for your insights.

I meant to say the squares of the radii above, sorry.
